# How to recursively create a game tree that asses probability of winning a Nim like game?

Tags: java, recursion, tree, artificial-intelligence, game-theory

I need help understanding how to go about recursively creating the game tree for a NIM like take away game. Once I create the tree I am supposed to use an unguided search on the tree to determine the probability of different moves leading to a win and the probability of my current state winning. I am using java for the project but I'm mostly looking for abstract solutions. There must be some way of using recursion and memoization to build this tree efficiently but I have hit a wall, any ideas would be of great help to me!

THE PROBLEM:
Consider a simple game consisting of a series of n tokens, played by 2 players. The players alternate turns. Each player must take at least one token, and can take no more than n/2 (fractions round down).The player who takes the last token loses

Output: For all values of n from 1 to 500, state the probability of the player ‘on the move’ winning, the
number of tokens they should select to maximize their chance of winning, and the likelihood of
winning if that number is taken.

I want to avoid hardcoding solutions but I know from trial and error that giving the opponent a token count that is equal to (2^n)-1 is an ideal move, but I want to be able to reach that conclusion from assessing the game tree.
I have done some research on the min-max approach for NIM trees but I'm not sure if that really helps me determine the probability of winning or just the best move.
Any ideas?

Comment: As far as I remember, Nim is "solved", in the sense that, under the assumption that both players are not insane and self-harming, it is immediately clear who "wins" and who "loses" just from the starting conditions. That is, playing nim is just as meaningful as declaring one of the players to be "the winner" right away. Where is there any place for probabilistic modeling? If I simply say "Let's play the NULL-game. You won. (with probability 1.0)", what's the point modeling it probabilistically? The only thing you could model probabilistically are the various levels of insanity of the players.

Comment: Ya but maybe a player chooses a less optimal move. If I can populate the tree that holds all the possibilities and then somehow search that tree for the best move. There must also be some way of calculating the strength of my position based on how many ways I can still win from that token amount and use that to calculate a probability of winning. Also, I assume a lot of the branches overlap so I want some way of keeping track of the basic branches so I don't have to redo them if that makes sense.